# passing value to route in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

my first controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(personalInfoModel personalInfo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        TempData["key"] = personalInfo.CNIC;

        PersonalInfoViewModel pivm = new PersonalInfoViewModel();
        pivm.AddNewRecord(personalInfo);

        return RedirectToAction("Create", "Experience", new { key = personalInfo.CNIC});
    }

    return View();
}
```

And my 2nd controller code is:

```
public ActionResult Create(string key)
{
    if (filled == true)
    {
        TempData["alertMessage"] = "<script>alert('Fill it first!')</script>";
    }
    filled = true;
    return View(key);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(experiencesModel experiences, string key)
{
    filled = false;
    ExperiencesViewModel evm = new ExperiencesViewModel();
    evm.AddNewRecord(experiences, key);
    return View();

}
```

I want to pass key from 1st controller to 2nd controller in which I am facing error:

> The view '42201-09007860-1' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Views/Experience/42201-09007860-1.aspx
>   ~/Views/Experience/42201-09007860-1.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/42201-09007860-1.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/42201-09007860-1.ascx
>   ~/Views/Experience/42201-09007860-1.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Experience/42201-09007860-1.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/42201-09007860-1.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/42201-09007860-1.vbhtml

How can I solve this issue? I need clarification about passing value from controller to controller.

Comment: There's a second overload to RedirectToAction that takes an object instead of a RouteValueDictionary. Maybe your new {} is wrongly recognized as object? Try creating a real RouteValueDictionary. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460311(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The first param to `View` is the name of the view to render. If you want to utilize the default view based on convention, you must pass null. The second param is where you can pass a model, which would likely be your `key`.

```
return View(null, key);
```

Or

```
return View("Create", key);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't fully understand the `return View()` code. Here's the difference between `View()` and `View("ViewName")`:

> `return View()` returns the view corresponding to the action method and 
>   `return View("ViewName")` returns the view name specified in the current view folder.

On this line:

```
return View(key);
```

You are trying to return the view that has the name that is provided in the `key` parameter, which won't work of course. If you want to view the `Create` page, just change it to following line:

```
return View("Create", key);
```